# Your app contains non-public API usage

Tags: ios, publish

I'm trying to submit my app on the App Store but I'm getting this msg:

```
Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the errors, correct them, and resubmit your application.
The app references non-public symbols in Payload/XXX.app/XXX: CFUserNotificationDisplayNotice
```

Where "XXX" -- application name.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: So are you using the `CFUserNotificationDisplayNotice()` function?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
No, I don't use this method... Even more I'm don't know this class..

Comment: @kroumvud: are you using any third-party libraries in your app ?

Comment: Yes, I'm use one custom library for sending special data to server.

Comment: Maybe try an extensive search on "CFUserNotificationDisplayNotice" in your project source, and your third-party libs sources as well...

Comment: I searched "CFUserNotificationDisplayNotice" in my project and do not get any results :(
Can to solve this issue with adding CoreFoundation library to the project?

Comment: Unfortunately, adding CoreFoundation library does not fixed this issue.
Any other ideas?

Comment: @kroumvud No, this isn't related to that. In what form does the 3rd-party library come? Source or binary?

Comment: @H2CO3 Unfortunately, I have only binary file.

Comment: @kroumvud Then do an `otool -tv | grep CFUserNotification` to the binary - if it finds anything, then the 3rd-party library uses that private function.

Comment: @H2CO3 I have tried to check lib with command `otool-tv lib.a | grep CFUserNotification` in the terminal, but output is empty :(
I can contact with developer of this library. What need to change in the lib sources for correct work?

Comment: @H2CO3 Also I'm tried other command `nm -arch armv7 lib.a | egrep CFUserNotification`.
In this case output in the terminal looks like:
`nm: no name list
nm: no name list
         U _CFUserNotificationDisplayNotice
nm: no name list
nm: no name list
nm: no name list
nm: no name list
nm: no name list
nm: no name list`

Comment: @k FYI, it's `otool -tv`, not `otool-tv` - the latter one doesn't exist, so it's natural you got an empty output from that.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm double checked command in terminal and enter command with "space" in the `otool -tv`, but nothing changed, output is empty

Comment: Thanks to all who responded, I was contacted with library developer and he rebuilt it without the CFUserNotificationDisplayNotice methods

Comment: How you came to know which library using CFUserNotification?.

Comment: @raj I had a only one third-party library in my app. But I think you can try to check all you libraries with otool command.

Answer (score -1):

A private API is an API that is not intended to be used by outside developers. This is to prevent breaking changes when the SDK is updated.

The behavior of a private API is not guaranteed. The methods may be removed in the future updates of the platform.

You can use the private API's in you OSX and iOS apps if you **don't** intend to release through Apple App Store, but then, again you yourself need to make sure that your app is not broken by the comming SDK/OS updates.

Either you or some third party framework in your bundle is using private APIs

Remove the signature mentioned from the code and you should be fine.