# "The app references non-public selectors in Payload"

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-privateapi

[image]

There are two SO questions I found that address debugging this:

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773841/your-app-contains-non-public-api-usage) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031356/finding-private-api-call-terminatewithstatus)

(1) One question recommends doing "`otool -tv | grep CFUserNotification` to the binary". Of course I changed out CFUserNotification for _deviceInfoForKey. I get this:

```
Binary file Lexly.app/Lexly matches
```

(2) The other question recommends doing `otool -L Lexly.app/Lexly` on the binary. I get a list of all the frameworks I added, repeated for each architecture.

How does this help me find the external libraries that are using the 3 offending selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this blog post](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/tutorial-finding-calls-to-uniqueidentifier-in-your-ios-app/) which explains, among other things, how to create a shell script in your project's root to find the offending selector.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for match in $(grep -lR uniqueIdentifier *); do
    printf "File: %s\n****************************************\n\n" "$match"
    strings $match | grep --context=15 uniqueIdentifier
    printf "\n\n\n"
done
```

Just replace `uniqueIdentifier` with whatever selector you need to find.

Turns out all three of those selectors were from a beta analytics library I included months ago and wasn't even using. This was an old project I resurrected.